# Modelling Power Prices

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Since electricity prices involve strong seasonality, jump components as well as negative prices and can not be modelled by the GBM, what models/distributions exist, which would allow for modelling these processes. If I remember correctly the Variance-Gamma Process allows for negative prices?

Answer (score 1):

This question should be defined a little more clearly. What purpose is the model to have? Are you modelling the prices for short-term (predictive basis), medium-term (risk basis) or long-term (investment basis)?

There are plenty of types of models for all purposes. Raphael Weron has plenty of research published on all this - even including some papers centered around summary of recent research. These should be accessible through e.g. Google Scholar.

Personally, I find Markov Regime-Switching models and jump-diffusion models fascinating for short-term and medium-term electricity price modelling.